# Does extending Article 50 legally require a new set date?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit, article-50

If the United Kingdom chose to apply for a delay to Article 50, must they set a new (target) date in order to do so?  Or could the UK <s>suspend</s> postpone Article 50 until further notice / indefinitely, without setting any new date?  My question is from a legal point of view; whether the EU-27 would agree with such a move, even if possible, is a separate question.

Comment: It's worth noting that we shouldn't talk of "delaying Article 50", "suspending Article 50", "revoking Article 50", etc. This choice of wording seems to be common throughout the media, but is incorrect. Article 50 is an article in the Treaty on European Union. To modify the article itself would require unanimous agreement amongst the treaty signatories, and is typically not the meaning intended by those that use these phrases. Instead we should talk of delaying/suspending/revoking etc. the *notice* that the UK gave in *accordance with* Article 50.

Comment: On another note, since this is a legal question, would it not be better placed on law.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The UK cannot **suspend** her Article 50 notification. It can merely **retract** the notification and that would have to be in good faith, i.e. with the intention to stay for the foreseeable future. So a retraction has no new set date.

The UK and EU27, acting unanimously, can **extend** the negotiation period as long as they like. I'm not aware of any rule that would force them to set a date. Note that this requires unanimity, while accepting a withdrawal agreement merely requires a qualified majority.

Article 50 was mostly written with the intention of never using it, so it is rather sketchy on details. Where beyond the article itself would one look for clarification? 50 (2) references [TFEU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_on_the_Functioning_of_the_European_Union), 50 (3) does not.

---

As I understand it:

- **Acting alone, the UK can:**
  Decide to Remain before March 29th.
  Force a hard Brexit (i.e. no deal) on March 29th.
- **A sufficient minority of the EU27 can:**
  Prevent any deal, leaving the UK the choice between Remain and hard Brexit.
- **The UK and a qualified majority of the EU27 can:**
  Make a deal for a soft Brexit on or before March 29th.
  Agree on a hard Brexit *before* March 29th (not that anybody wants that).
- **The UK and *all* of the EU27 can:**
  Set a date later than March 29th for the default hard Brexit, and keep negotiating for any of the other options. *I believe they could also set no date and keep negotiating.*

---

Follow-up: The BBC also [writes](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-46894544) that Article 50 can't be paused, only revoked or extended.

Comment: This may be an English language question, but what is the difference between "suspend" and "extend without a date"?

Comment: @gerrit, as I understand it "suspending" Article 50 would suspend the Brexit negotiations, which is clearly not the intention of anybody in the UK but the Remainer minority. Using the process described in 50 (3) to extend the period, with or without a specific date, would keep Article 50 and the negotiations open.

Comment: Aha.  I clearly meant an indefinite extension, I will clarify the question.

Comment: @gerrit, the UK cannot do that postpone Brexit by itself. They can ask the EU27 to postpone Brexit, or they can withdraw Brexit on their own, or they can go through with it.

Comment: I know they need unanimous approval to postpone Brexit, and I suspect they're unlikely to get that if there's no date on the postponement; I just wondered if the latter is even possible in theory.

Comment: In your summary, you mean "soft brexit" = "brexit with a deal", and "hard brexit" = "brexit without a deal"?  I'm asking because 3 years ago, a Brexit deal where the UK would leave Customs Union and Single Market would have been called a "hard Brexit".

Comment: @gerrit, yes, expectations have slipped since then.

Comment: @o.m. It is very possible that "Remainer minority" are statistically the majority now for two reasons See e.g. https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/brexit-leave-eu-remain-vote-support-against-poll-uk-europe-final-say-yougov-second-referendum-peter-a8541971.html and https://greenworld.org.uk/article/remainers-now-majority-says-channel-4-brexit-poll although of course you can probably find opposing data. Anyway one massive driver for this being such a mess is that there is no clear popular majority as implied by your "except a Remainer minority". Pleasing everyone is not possible.

Comment: It's worth noting that we shouldn't talk of "delaying Article 50", "suspending Article 50", "revoking Article 50", etc. This choice of wording seems to be common throughout the media, but is incorrect. Article 50 is an article in the Treaty on European Union. To modify the article itself would require unanimous agreement amongst the treaty signatories, and is typically not the meaning intended by those that use these phrases. Instead we should talk of delaying/suspending/revoking etc. the notice that the UK gave in accordance with Article 50

Comment: Also, note that whilst the UK can't suspend the exit date, they can (theoretically at least) achieve the same affect by revoking the notice and submitting a new one (thus creating a new two year period).

Comment: @JBentley while some people have suggested they could do that, others on the EU side have characterised a revocation as needing to be in "good faith". I suspect such shenanigans would be viewed extremely dimly.

Comment: @JBentley, I edited to clarify that it is the notification which would be retracted.

Comment: @mbrig Yes that is true, but I am referring only to the legal possibilities, as OP specified that he is only interested in that, and specifically isn't interested on what the political views would be.

Answer (score 10):

Article 50, Paragraph 3 of the Treaty of the European Union states (emphasis mine):

> The Treaties shall cease to apply to the State in question from the date of entry into force of
>   the withdrawal agreement or, failing that, two years after the notification referred to in
>   paragraph 2, **unless the European Council, in agreement with the Member State concerned,
>   unanimously decides to extend this period**.

As the Treaty is silent on the requirement for any end date, it can be assumed that the Treaty allows for an indefinite extension, provided unanimous consent is given.

Furthermore, there is no mechanism for the UK to unilaterally "suspend" its exit from the European Union.  The European Court of Justice [ruled last month](http://curia.europa.eu/juris/document/document.jsf;jsessionid=30070EAD3C16AB345376A71509ACC49D?text=&docid=208636&pageIndex=0&doclang=EN&mode=req&dir=&occ=first&part=1) that the UK can unilaterally revoke its notice of intention to leave "in an unequivocal and unconditional manner"; in other words, without intending to send another such notification in the imminent future.

Additionally, it must be noted that the date and time of withdrawal is currently coded into UK law.  Before any request for extension can be legally made, the [European Union (Withdrawal) Act](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2018/16/contents/enacted) will need to be amended by the UK Parliament to allow for a different date.

Comment: Re changing the date and time: if that changes (by agreement between the UK and EU), section 20(4) of the Act allows the government to change the date in the Act to match the new one (subject to approval by both houses of Parliament - Schedule 7, Part 2, section 14 of the Act).

Comment: It seems to me like there's no _functional_ difference between requiring an end date on an extension or not.  If a date is required, just pick "31 December 9999" and you effectively have an indefinite extension anyway.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle chances are at least one member state will object to making such long commitments. Since support must be unanimous, that would mean it wouldn't get extended.

Comment: @JJJ Likely true - but my point was that it's moot whether the Treaty allows for indefinite extensions or not.  If a member state would object to a 9999 end date, they'd equally object to an indefinite extension as both are equivalent.